# openSIPS WSS permission denied on bind any port

Tags: debian, sip, voip, opensips

I'm trying to configure openSIPS and RTPEngine on a Debian 8.10 server but when I set WSS in opensips.cfg and restart it I get this error with any port I tried:

```
ERROR:core:tcp_init_listener: bind(b, 0x7fe77b0c0e5c, 16) on 192.168.0.143:555 : Permission denied
ERROR:core:trans_init_all_listeners: failed to init listener [192.168.0.143], proto wss
```

In /etc/default/opensips I set USER / GROUP to root and when I restarted openssips I had root privilages in an SSH terminal, but the same happens if I log into the server directly.

In the openSISP Documentation it is stated that you need super user privilages because the port 443 needs it. But I don't see how I can get higher access then root and also any other port I tried isn't privilaged so it should work, but it doesn't.

What could be the problem? How can I solve this?

Comment: Did you double-check your `systemd` settings? Just list the package contents and locate the file. I often find it that it overrides what I place within `/etc/default/opensips`.

Comment: Thanks. I checked and in the opensips.service file for the user/group opensips was defined so the service ignored my settings in the default file

Answer (score 1):

I was facing same issues and I have changed user and group from opensips to root  and it's get resolved you can try.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Great answer, I also changed my user and group to root.
Run the command ``sudo systemctl daemon-reload`` before starting opensips.